# How to retrieve tweets using codebird.php

Tags: php, twitter

I'm trying to use Codebird to show my latest tweet on a simple website. Unfortunately, I can't manage to make it work.
Here's what I did for now. 
I created my App on Twitter Developer page. I obtained my Key/Secret and then my Token/Secret. Then I wrote my small PHP script and tried to show the timeline just to see if everything works. Here I encountered the problems. The code goes like this:

```
<?php
require_once ('codebird.php');
\Codebird\Codebird::setConsumerKey(MY_KEY, MY_SECRET); 

$cb = \Codebird\Codebird::getInstance();
$cb->setToken(MY_TOKEN, MY_TOKEN_SECRET);
$reply = (array) $cb->statuses_homeTimeline();
print_r($reply);
?>
```

(and obviously I put the various key strings in the correct arguments).

This code gives my an Array ( [httpstatus] => 0 ). So I tried

```
print_r($reply[0]);
```

But then nothing is printed out in the page.

Where am I wrong? How should I modify this code to get my last tweet? I'm a bit new with the new Twitter API, and a lot of stuff confuses me.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: how did you get the token?

Comment: I clicked on the "Get token" button at the end of the App Page in the Twitter Developer site. Now in my page I can see both the Consumer key/secret and the token key/secret.

Comment: I'm not sure where to find the error logs. Anyway, the developers dashboard in Safari doesn't find errors. Puzzled.

Answer (score 0):

I copied and pasted your code and it's not working.
I get error regarding the CodeBird class

Try:

```
require_once ('codebird.php');
Codebird::setConsumerKey('key', 'secret key'); 
$cb = Codebird::getInstance();
$cb->setToken('token', 'secret token');
$reply = (array) $cb->statuses_homeTimeline();
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work just fine.

```
<?php

use Codebird\Codebird;
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$cb = new Codebird;
$cb->setConsumerKey(
    'Consumer_Key',
    'Consumer_Secret'
);
$cb->setToken(
    'Access_Token',
    'Access_Token_Secret'
);    

$reply = (array)$cb->statuses_homeTimeline();  

echo '<pre>';
print_r($reply);
```